# Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer in android Map v2.? How to solve?

Tags: android, exception, dictionary

```
   I am integrating google map v2 and i got these below errors in logcat, so what happen wrong with code:
```

My code is below:

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();

    if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            UiSettings mUiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
            mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        }
```

and my logcat is below:

```
04-20 09:48:03.870: E/System(28491): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.close(RandomAccessFile.java:166)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.finalize(RandomAccessFile.java:175)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
    04-20 09:48:04.050: E/System(28491):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: what is UiSettings class? post it.

Comment: @SimplePlan, i havent used UIsetting class, i have code that i have posted above, Thanks